# Can't stash a single file?

Tags: git, merge, pull

I'm on a public `develop` branch and trying to pull the most updated changes. When executing the command, I get notified that:

```
From https://vantaca.visualstudio.com/Vantaca/_git/VantacaSystem
 - [deleted]             (none)     -> origin/feature/van-2599
 * [new branch]          Feature/van-2599 -> origin/Feature/van-2599
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
        ReleaseScripts/importValidationGLForInterest.sql
Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge.
Aborting
Updating 2aa556b25..9308bb964
```

I tried stashing my local changes:

```
git stash -- ReleaseScripts/ImportValidationGLForInterest.sql
```

and then tried pulling `develop` again but i seem to be getting the same issue.

I don't care about the local changes since I never touched this file, I was considering using `git --reset hard` but this is a public branch and I'm nervous of messing with it.

Comment: If you don't care about the file changes, you could restore it? `git restore ReleaseScripts/importValidationGLForInterest.sql`?

Comment: `.sql` sounds like a database file that probably should not be committed in the first place. But as for the question in the title: `git stash` makes *commits* and every commit holds every file. Using `git stash push -- <pathspec>` just restricts the commits so that files *not* listed in the pathspec match the current commit. Having done the commit, Git then resets those files so that they match the current commit. If the file doesn't "stay reset", something complicated is going on, such as file name collisions with case folding, or CRLF-translation, or something else complicated.

Answer (score 0):

> I was considering using git --reset hard but this is a public branch and I'm nervous of messing with it.

The `git reset --hard` is a *local* operation, which won't affect its history, since HEAD won't move. Only your local index and working tree will be reset.

Once `git status` is clean (reports no local modification), you can try the pull once more.